# Under which conditions discrete versions of convex\concave function are submodular/supermodular?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, combinatorial-optimization

I have $f(x)$ with $x \in [0,1]$ and $f(x)$ is convex, then, under which conditions discrete function which is defined as $f(x_h)$ on discrete subset of $[0,1]$, for example, $x_h \in \{0, h, 2h, \dots, 1\}$ is submodular?

I know about Lovasz extension, but it works in other way: given discrete function it builds extension function which convexity proves submodularity of given function (and vice versa, submodularity of given function proves convexity of extension function).

Comment: This question has received only very little attention so far -- maybe you wish to edit.

Comment: @StefanKohl thank you for suggestion! Is it clear now?

Comment: I don't know -- it's not my field. -- I just noticed that your question had been viewed on average less than once per week, and so I suggested an edit to draw some more attention.